# Move column values to values with True/False

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I have a dataset similar to this one:

```
 data = {'lat': [0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.25, 0.25, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48],
        'lon': [0.87, 0.87, 0.87, 0.87, 0.12, 0.12, 0.59, 0.59, 0.59, 0.59],
        'animal': ['dog', 'cat', 'rat', 'rat', 'cat', 'rat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'rat'],
        'category': ['A', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C']}
mdf = pd.DataFrame(data)

mdf
Out[460]: 
    lat   lon animal category
0  0.15  0.87    dog        A
1  0.15  0.87    cat        C
2  0.15  0.87    rat        B
3  0.15  0.87    rat        C
4  0.25  0.12    cat        B
5  0.25  0.12    rat        B
6  0.48  0.59    cat        C
7  0.48  0.59    dog        A
8  0.48  0.59    dog        C
9  0.48  0.59    rat        C
```

I want to use 'animal', 'lat' and 'lon' as some kind of indexes to obtain something like this:

```
      lat   lon animal     A      B      C
0    0.15  0.87    dog True   False  False
1    0.15  0.87    cat False  False  True
2    0.15  0.87    rat False  True   True
4    0.25  0.12    cat False  True   False
5    0.25  0.12    rat False  True   False
6    0.48  0.59    cat False  False  True
7    0.48  0.59    dog True   False  True
9    0.48  0.59    rat False  False  True
```

I don't really care wether it is True/False, 1/0, etc. as long as I can see which categories each combination of 'lat', 'long' and 'animal' has.

I've been trying without success several alternatives: pivot, pivot_table, groupby, stack/unstack... but none seems to answer my needs.

The only option I have left is to iterate through the different 'lat', 'lon', 'animal' alternatives and check wether there is an occurence for each of the 'category'.

Maybe this could be done somehow by defining 'lat', 'lon', 'animal' as indexes and "unmelting" somehow

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

---

EDIT: I am unable to have new lines in comments, and I don't know how to contact the person that closed the post, so let me bring some additional explanation here. Apologies for the annoyance.

Quang, thanks for your reference to a different thread. However, I am not sure it helps me.

I could do this:

```
pd.get_dummies(mdf['category'], prefix='', prefix_sep='')
```

But I get my initial 10 lines instead of the table I was aiming at.

To obtain something useful with get_dummies, I would have to do this:

```
mdf = mdf.join(pd.get_dummies(mdf['category'], prefix='', prefix_sep=''))
mdf[['A', 'B', 'C']] = mdf.groupby(['lat', 'lon', 'animal'])[['A', 'B', 'C']].transform('sum')
mdf.drop_duplicates(subset=['lat', 'lon', 'animal'], inplace=True)
d = {1: True,
     0: False}
mdf[['A', 'B', 'C']] = mdf[['A', 'B', 'C']].replace(d)
mdf.drop('category',
        axis=1,
        inplace=True)
```

But this seems overcomplicated and I feel there must have a better way...

I also thought about this:

```
mdf['value'] = [True] * 10
mdf = mdf.set_index(['lat', 'lon', 'animal', 'category'])
mdf = mdf.unstack(fill_value=False)
mdf = mdf.reset_index()
mdf.columns = ['lat', 'lon', 'animal', 'A', 'B', 'C']
```

But again, it seems so un-pythonic to trick the system by playing with indexes...

There must surely be a better way!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I the original index values do not matter, you could use `get_dummies` to concat the `A`, `B` and `C` columns to the original dataframe, then group by lat lon and animal and sum the boolean columns:

```
categs = np.sort(mdf['category'].unique())

resul = pd.concat([mdf, pd.get_dummies(mdf['category']).astype(bool)], axis=1
                  ).groupby(['lat', 'lon', 'animal'])[categs].sum().reset_index()
```

it gives:

```
    lat   lon animal      A      B      C
0  0.15  0.87    cat  False  False   True
1  0.15  0.87    dog   True  False  False
2  0.15  0.87    rat  False   True   True
3  0.25  0.12    cat  False   True  False
4  0.25  0.12    rat  False   True  False
5  0.48  0.59    cat  False  False   True
6  0.48  0.59    dog   True  False   True
7  0.48  0.59    rat  False  False   True
```

Comment: Merci @serge-ballesta, I really like it. It's similar in concept to my first suggestion but far more elegant and streamlined.

I'm struggling to understand in this part `groupby(['lat', 'lon', 'animal'])[categs]` why you need the `[categs]`? Is it a best practice such as `.loc()` to select rows? It seems it would make a difference with `.transform()` but not with `.sum()`.

Thanks.